# WKWebView goes blank after memory warning

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I'm developing an iOS app that will show some 360 panoramic content in a wkWebView. The page does load, but when it receives a memory warning, it shows a blank view on iPad 2.

Relevant code:

```
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://360yerevan.com/mobilembed/91001/"] ];


NSString *jScript = @"var meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);";

WKUserScript *wkUScript = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:jScript injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];
WKUserContentController *wkUController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
[wkUController addUserScript:wkUScript];

WKWebViewConfiguration *wkWebConfig = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
wkWebConfig.userContentController = wkUController;
wkWebConfig.processPool = [[WKProcessPool alloc] init];

WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:wkWebConfig];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView loadRequest:req];
```

This works fine on iPhone 5/5S.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I am investigating this problem as well. In our case it seems that the sandboxed WkWebView.WebContent process is crashing leaving the blank screen in the App.

Where did you see the memory warning, can you share these logs?

We are discussing the issue here:
https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView/issues/41

Comment: Maybe you can try keeping a strong reference to the webView.

Answer (score 12):

One major cause of this is the WebContent process crashing.

In iOS 9 and above you can use the WKNavigationDelegate method `webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate` to catch this case. It's up to you to decide how to respond to the crash, but if reloading the page is enough, then `[webView reload]` will do the trick as shown below. As @ray mentions in the comments, you will not get any useful information about the *why* of the crash from this delegate call.

```
- (void)webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate:(WKWebView *)webView {
    // Reload current page, since we have crashed the WebContent process
    // (most likely due to memory pressure)
    [webView reload];
}
```

In iOS8 and below, you can check if `myWKWebViewInstance.title` is nil.

Comment: Everyone should know that this delegate method provides **no** useful information about the cause, nor does it necessarily fire for OOM events. **Sometimes WKWV will simply stop rendering content without calling this delegate**. Still seeing this bad behavior in iOS 12.

Comment: @ray is there any article that explain why just top rendering without calling this delegate...also I find that when webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate happen,the  wkwv will remove different views in different iphone which is lower than 12...sometimes it show transparent sometimes just white screen..