# WKWebView crashes at 30M of RAM usage on iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView that loads a custom HTML file from our server. In our app there's a button to change the web page's font size using JavaScript by iterating through all elements and set their `style` property(this should be irrelevant since on other iOS it works perfectly).

On iOS 9 devices, when the font gets larger and larger, the webview gets progressively slower to respond to the font change. For example, changing from 22px to 24px takes 2s to take effect, and changing from 24px to 26px can take 3s or more. Eventually, when the font size gets to 28px, the webview would crash the app with a memory warning in the console. If not connect to Xcode, however, it would not crash but turn into a blank screen as described in this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565301/wkwebview-goes-blank-after-memory-warning).

This is not a duplicate since I'm asking for something different:

I have implemented `webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate` and can confirm it gets called, but when I try to reload the webView it simply crashes again and fall into a crash-reload-crash loop. The Xcode panel shows my memory is using 31M of RAM, which like 5% for my iPhone 4S, so this shouldn't be a *true* memory issue. The web page consists of paragraphs of texts only, so **is this a system bug or something that I'm doing wrong?** Please comment if you need more details.

Here's my code:

```
class ReaderController: UIViewController {

    // loads webView, injects JavaScript, handles button, etc.

    func loadData() {
        let html = // get html 
        webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: htmlURL)
    }
}

extension ReaderController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate(_ webView: WKWebView) {
        loadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it really important to support iOS 9? This likely represents a very tiny percentage of your user base. Of course, there are legitimate reasons to support iOS 9. Just checking.

Comment: Yes it is, and in fact, this is a Lite version of our app targeted specifically for lower-end devices. That's why iOS 9 for this app is essential. @Daniel

Comment: Can you provide a minimal HTML that replicates the problem?